# Get rid of PULSE_* environmental variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, nx, nomachine

How can I get rid of these environmental variables?

```
fryking@heimdal:~$ printenv | grep PULSE
PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG=/usr/NX/var/run/nxdevice/D-1002-02BEA0333F591B469FD130F503B146D4/audio/client.conf
PULSE_SERVER=/usr/NX/var/run/nxdevice/D-1002-02BEA0333F591B469FD130F503B146D4/audio/native.socket
PULSE_CONFIG=/usr/NX/var/run/nxdevice/D-1002-02BEA0333F591B469FD130F503B146D4/audio/daemon.conf
PULSE_SCRIPT=/usr/NX/var/run/nxdevice/D-1002-02BEA0333F591B469FD130F503B146D4/audio/default.pa
```

Background is that pulseaudio does not work. It can't find the above configuration file. If I unset PULSE_* in a shell, pulseaudio works. But if I open a new shell. They are there again...

I have tried these commands without finding the origin of the PULSE_* environmental variables:

```
grep -rsn PULSE /etc
grep -rns PULSE ~/.profile
grep -rsn PULSE ~/.bashrc
```

Also, I have uninstalled nomachine on the server ..

Comment: `/.profile` and `/.bashrc` generally don't exist; you want `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`. And also `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` if either exists. Also, as @JasonMartin said, they're probably not set literally, so you need to look for `source`, `.`, and `eval` commands.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I ment to write ~/.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That filename looks dynamic, so look instead for a script that generates them -- something will be `source`d or `.` loaded, or possibly `eval`.

Comment: Thanks. The hard truth is that a reboot solved the problem. I guess the file exporting the PULSE_* variables were deleted by the nomachine uninstall. But the exports were still lingering on and applied to each new bash session. What do I know :)